# SQL Divide Function not working in Metabase

Tags: sql, database, metabase

In my Metabase, I wrote a query `SELECT 10/5` It showing a result **2.000000000** which is correct.

But When I wrote  `SELECT 5/10` It showing a result **0.000000000**. The result should show **0.500000000**.

Can you explain it? Why divide function is not working?

Comment: Does it work if you do `select 5.0/10`?

Answer (score 0):

Metabase can parse SQL different ways. It depends on connector type.

But in most cases, the result depends on the data type.

Your example uses [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient), because both of operands are integer.

You can just try to change the data type
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is rounding off the value,

Like for select 7/5 it will print 1.

Comment: How to remove the rounding?